# How to put background image in select option tag using css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a country dropdown list receiving from json response, and want to add respective country flag icons (getting the images as well from json reponse) next to the country names.

I have tried different jQuery and bootstrap plugins for that but what they are doing is ruining my previous select box styling and are adding their own ones dynamically.

I want to achieve this using CSS only.

Code tried so far :

```
<select class="form-control icon-menu" name="country" id="country_id" onchange="fetchCountryCode(this.value);">
   <?php
       foreach ($countries as $countriesList) {
         echo '<option value=' . $countriesList['id'] .' style=" background-image : url('. $countriesList['flag_url'] .')" data-imagecss="flag ad">' . $countriesList['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
select.icon-menu option {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left;
    padding-left:30px;
}
</style>
```

But not getting any results, i am stucked pls help

Comment: shouldnt inline css look like this ? `style="background-image: url();"`

Comment: oops....my mistake dint noticed, i corrected it though. But still images are not there :( This is what i got after inspect element in chrome: `<option value="1" style=" background-image : url(http://assets.mvendr.com/flags/64/ZA.png)" data-imagecss="flag ad">South Africa</option>`

Comment: its visible in mozilla firefox though....but image is not showing when country is selected

Comment: pls provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: @VIVEKRAJ: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q27fortw/

Comment: Then how should i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't give an option tag a background-image.

One solution will be to create your own "select" component.

```
<ul>
     <li>option1</li>
     <li>option2></li>
     ..
</ul>
```

then you give some css to look like a select input.

And some javascript to handle showing and hiding "li" elements

Comment: You must to use a plugin because if you try to develop a select plugin you lost many time. The plugin that I recommend to you is chosen of jQuery, or select2 of jQuery too. https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ It runs effectively